# Decimal Formatting for Static Methods

Tags: java

Edit: The book has a typo with cylinder and used volume instead, but the point of the program is to exercise working with static methods so it doesn't matter.

I finished this program and got it working to get the static methods to interact with my main class. I'm just having an issue with decimal formatting. I get 11 decimal places with the doubles. I've tried using DecimalFormat, but that doesn't have any affect, no matter where I put it. Do I need to do something extra because of working with static methods now?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat; //import DecimalFormat

class Area{

    //Area of a Circle
    static double Area(double radius){
        return Math.PI * (radius * radius);
    }

    //Area of a Rectangle
    static int Area(int width, int length){
        return width * length;
    }

    //Volume of a Cyclinder
    static double Area(double radius, double height){
        return Math.PI * (radius * radius) * height;
    }
}

public class AreaDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Variable Declarations for each shape
        double circleRadius = 20.0;
        int rectangleLength = 10;
        int rectangleWidth = 20;
        double cylinderRadius = 10.0;
        double cylinderHeight = 15.0;

        //Print Statements for the Areas
        System.out.println("The area of a circle with a radius of " + circleRadius + " is " + Area.Area(circleRadius)); //Circle
        System.out.println("The area of a rectangle with a length of " + rectangleLength + " width of " + rectangleWidth + " is " + Area.Area(rectangleLength, rectangleWidth)); //Rectangle
        System.out.println("The area of a cylinder with radius " + cylinderRadius + " and height " + cylinderHeight + " is " + Area.Area(cylinderRadius, cylinderHeight)); //Cylinder
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a decimalFormat you can like this,

```
double d = 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

This would print out 1.23. If you increase the format to `"#.###` it would be 1.235

Or more applicable to you would be

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
//Print Statements for the Areas
System.out.println("The area of a circle with a radius of " + df.format(circleRadius) + " is " + df.format(Area.Area(circleRadius))); //Circle
// do same for your others
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

I changed 

`Area.Area(cylinderRadius, cylinderHeight)`

to

`df.format(Area.Area(cylinderRadius, cylinderHeight))`

and etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between your `decimal format` and `Static methods`

And to control the precision of floating point arithmetic, you should use `java.math.BigDecimal.`

or use [Decimal Format with Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: float and double were designed to be used in mathematical calculations.  You use BigDecimal when you're dealing with currency or money, where precision is important.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Agreed Gil,I informed that and Added the Decimal format pattern constructor for his requirement.